# What can be learned for number theory from geometrical constructions (and vice versa)?

Tags: geometry, number-theory, euclidean-geometry, big-picture

Even though [this question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309243/a-general-form-of-mathematical-problems-and-results) was not so well received at MO I'd like to pick two examples and make a question out of them here.

Consider these two pairs of **geometrical** constructions which yield the same **arithmetical** results:

> 1. Constructing the **half** $x/2$ for **one** given positive real $x$ in two different ways.
> 2. Constructing the **product** $mn$ for **two** given positive integers $m, n$ in two different ways.

It's noteworthy that in each of these pairs one of the constructions does make use of circles while the other one doesn't.

### Example 1: Constructing the half $x/2$

You can create the half $\mathsf{X}/2$ of a positive real $\mathsf{X}$ by two  different Euclidean constructions:

1. [image]
2. [image]

### Example 2: Constructing the product $mn$

You can create the product $nm$ of two positive integers $n, m$ by two different Euclidean constructions:

1. creating a **rectangle**
    [image]

    and counting **the number of unit squares** that fit into the rectangle
2. creating a **line segment**
    [image]

    and counting **the number of unit lengths** that fit into the line segment

---

In both cases it's not obvious that the two constructions always yield the same result, but for the sake of the theories (i.e. Euclid's – later Descartes' – geometry and number theory, resp. arithmetic geometry) it's essential.

---

My questions are:

> 1. How did (possibly) Euclid **formulate** the two statements above, i.e. that the two pairs of constructions always yield the same results?
> 2. How did (possibly) Euclid **prove** these statements?
> 3. What are the deep **insights** which we gain from understanding why these two pairs of constructions always yield the same result? (The
>      same *point* in Example 1, the same *positive integer* in Example 2.)

Answer (score 2):

Addressing only the title of your Q.

Farey-sequences are a useful tool in elementary Number Theory. Let  $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb N$ such that $a/b$ and $c/d$ are in lowest terms and $a/b<c/d.$ We say $a/b,c/d $ are  Farey-adjacent iff for all  $e,f\in \Bbb N$ such that $a/b<e/f<c/d,$ we have $f>\max (b,d).$

An important property is that if $a/b,c/d$ are Farey-adjacent then $|ad-bc|=1.$ This can be proven algebraically. In "Introduction To Geometry" by Coxeter, it is shown how to prove it geometrically:

If $a/b,c/d$ are Farey-adjacent then we can easily show there is a finite sequence $T_1,..., T_n$ of affine  area-preserving  maps from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$ such that $T=\prod_{i=1}^nT_i$ maps the triangle with vertices $(0,0),(a,b),(c,d)$ onto the triangle with vertices $(0,0), (1,0),(0,1). $ The area of the $\triangle$ with vertices $(0,0)(a,b),(c,d)$ is  $\frac {1}{2}|ad-bc|$  while  the area of the $\triangle$ with vertices $(0,0),(1,0)(0,1)$ is $\frac {1}{2}.$

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer for example 1 part 2.  Intersecting circles of the same diameter have a line of symmetry through the two points of intersection and could be loosely considered deep insight into a method of dividing x (in this case the distance between circle centers) into two equal parts.

Answer (score 0):

**Concerning the product $nm$**

The "essence" of the first construction is

$$n\times m = m + m + \dots + m\ \ (n \text{ times})$$

The "essence" of the second construction is

$$n \cdot m = n/(1/m)$$

That they are equivalent – i.e. $n \times m = n \cdot m$ – means

$$n/(1/m) = m + m + \dots + m\ \ (n \text{ times})$$

Because they are equivalent one may drop the multiplication sign:

$$nm := n \times m = n \cdot m$$

For symmetry reasons the first construction also shows that

$$m + m + \dots + m\ \ (n \text{ times}) = n + n + \dots + n\ \ (m \text{ times})$$

For symmetry reasons the second construction also shows that

$$n/(1/m) = m/(1/n)$$

By the second construction it can be nicely shown that

$$(1 + 1) \cdot 1/2 = 1$$